# Rails3.1 infinite/endless scroll

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari, infinite-scroll

I want to make my project's feed_item go endless, 
I am using kaminari in Rails, can anyone suggest a good way to implement infinite/endless scroll rather than this: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery ?
The referred resource seem staled, at least not working with me.
Please help.

Comment: Check this RailsCast episode: http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page